# To extract distinct values for all categorical columns in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a situation where I need to print all the distinct values that are there for all the categorical columns in my data frame
The dataframe looks like this :

```
Gender  Function  Segment
M       IT        LE
F       IT        LM
M       HR        LE
F       HR        LM
```

The output should give me the following:

```
Variable_Name    Distinct_Count
Gender           2
Function         2
Segment          2
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

using `nunique` then passing the series into a new datafame and setting column names.

```
df_unique = df.nunique().to_frame().reset_index()
df_unique.columns = ['Variable','DistinctCount']
```

---

```
print(df_unique)
   Variable  DistinctCount
0    Gender              2
1  Function              2
2   Segment              2
```

Comment: Nice one! This is probably what I was missing and made it the hard way :P

Comment: no need to loop when someone has made it easy for us and created nice methods :) @CeliusStingher

Answer (score 1):

This is not good, yet it won't fail to provide the expected output:

```
new_data = {'Variable_Name':[],'Distinct_Count':[]}
for i in list(df):
    new_data['Variable_Name'].append(i)
    new_data['Distinct_Count'].append(df[i].nunique())
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
  Variable_Name  Distinct_Count
0        Gender               2
1      Function               2
2       Segment               2
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the dataset you are using has only categorical, you can make use of pandas function describe().

for example:

```
df_unique = df.describe().iloc[[1]].T
```

df_unique will be a dataframe with 2 columns, 1 categorical variables and another with the number of unique values of corresponding categorical columns.